# start and stop azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell, shell

How to start and stop list of azure vm through command line like powershell script or shell script.
Please suggest. we have list of VM and resourcegroup in file. on single server working fine but mutltiple having issue.

```
input file like:-

rg01 vm01
rg01 vm02
rg02 vm03


its in same subscription
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

File contains:

[image]

```
$VAMMO = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Downloads\vammo1.txt"
foreach ($EMO in $VAMMO) {
    $v = $EMO -split ' '
    $rg = $v[0]
    $vn = $v[1]
    Write-Host "Starting VM"
    Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vn -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Stopping VM"
    Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vn -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
```

Output:

[image]